# or_reduce functionality

Tags: vhdl

what is the functionality of "or_reduce" function in VHDL ?

Comment: Have you tried googling or any other kind of search? The top hit for "vhdl or_reduce" looks like a plausible explanation.

Answer (score 5):

crazyscot is quite right.  Here's a precis:

It takes a `std_logic_vector` and returns the result of using the VHDL `OR` operator to or all the bits together. So if there's a `X`, `Z`, `U` etc in the vector, you'll get the "strongest" of these back.

Comment: what is the ieee library (package) to use to get this ?

Comment: std_logic_misc - despite being compiled into the IEEE library, it was not standardised (at least at the time of writing the answer :D) - here is one potential implementation google found for me: https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/blob/master/libraries/synopsys/std_logic_misc.vhdl